# Tensorflowのc_api.hにて画像を推論（VGG16のファインチューニング）したいのですが、TF_SessionRunが成功しません。どこを直せばいいでしょうか？

Tags: c, tensorflow

下記のような、VGG16をファインチューニングしたものをc++（推論部分はc）で作成したく考えています。
opancvで画像を読み込み、（1,224,224,3)へ変換したものを用いています。
出力部分は、６個への分類になります。

pythonを用いてファインチューニングしたグラフはpb化しています。
（tensorflow1.5使用」)
その際の学習画像は下記です。

```
temp_img_array=img_to_array(temp_img)
temp_img_array=temp_img_array.astype('float32')/255.0
temp_img_array=temp_img_array.reshape((1,224,224,3))
```

どこをどうすればいいのか教えていただきたくお願いします。

```
Hello from TensorFlow C library version 2.3.0
image > 224 x 224 x 3
--- graph info ---
input_1
block1_conv1/kernel
block1_conv1/kernel/read
block1_conv1/bias
；
；
dense_1/bias
dense_1/bias/read
dense_2/MatMul
dense_2/BiasAdd
dense_2/Softmax
--- graph info ---
```

入力のテンソルの形がおかしいと思うのですが、

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>
#include "tf_utils.hpp"

#define MODEL_FILENAME  "ep_156_ls_0.1.pb"
#define INPUTIMAGEPATH  "Valid_pic/"
#define INPUTIMAGENAME  "Valid_pic/ten__146.bmp"
#define IMAGE_BATCH     1
#define IMAGE_SIZE      224
#define IMAGE_CH        3

#define LAYERNAME_INPUT  "input_1"
#define LAYERNAME_OUTPUT "dense_2/Softmax"

static int displayGraphInfo()
{
    TF_Graph* graph = tf_utils::LoadGraph(MODEL_FILENAME);
    if (graph == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Can't load graph" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    size_t pos = 0;
    TF_Operation* oper;
    printf("--- graph info ---\n");
    while ((oper = TF_GraphNextOperation(graph, &pos)) != nullptr) {
        printf("%s\n", TF_OperationName(oper));
    }
    printf("--- graph info ---\n");

    TF_DeleteGraph(graph);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());

    /* read input image data */
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(INPUTIMAGENAME);
    cv::imshow("InputImage", image);

    /* convert to 224 x 224 RGB image (normalized: 0 ~ 1.0) */
    cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
    cv::resize(image, image, cv::Size(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE));
    cv::imshow("InputImage for CNN", image);
    image.convertTo(image, CV_32FC1, 1.0 / 255);

    std::cout << "image > " << image.rows << " x " << image.cols << " x " << image.channels() << std::endl;
 //   std::cout <<  image.data << std::endl;

    /* get graph info */
    displayGraphInfo();

    TF_Graph* graph = tf_utils::LoadGraph(MODEL_FILENAME);
    if (graph == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Can't load graph" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    /* prepare input tensor */
    std::vector<TF_Output> inputs;
    TF_Output input_op = { TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, LAYERNAME_INPUT), 0 };
    if (input_op.oper == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Can't init input_op" << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }
    inputs.push_back(input_op);

    const std::vector<std::int64_t> input_dims = { IMAGE_BATCH, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_CH };      // こことデータ次元あっていないと例外がスローされる
    const std::vector<std::int64_t> output_dims = {  1, 6 };

    std::vector<std::vector<float>> input_vals(IMAGE_BATCH);
    for (int b = 0; b < IMAGE_BATCH; b++)
    {
        input_vals[b].reserve(IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_CH);
        std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
        for (int r = 0; r < image.rows; r++)
        {
            input_vals[b].insert(input_vals[b].end(), image.ptr<float>(r), image.ptr<float>(r) + IMAGE_CH);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "OK)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "input_vals (size)" << input_vals.size() << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << " > " << input_vals[0][i] << " , ";

    }

    std::vector<TF_Tensor*> input_values;
    TF_Tensor* input_tensor = tf_utils::CreateTensor(TF_FLOAT,
        input_dims.data(), input_dims.size(),
        image.data, image.rows *image.cols*image.channels()  * sizeof(float));
    input_values.push_back(input_tensor);

    std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "type of tensor element > " << TF_TensorType(input_tensor) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "number of Dimensions   > " << TF_NumDims(input_tensor) << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < TF_NumDims(input_tensor); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "   dimension "<< i << "> " << TF_Dim(input_tensor,i) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "size of type           > " << TF_TensorByteSize(input_tensor) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pointer                > " << TF_TensorData(input_tensor) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "No of element          > " << TF_TensorElementCount(input_tensor) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "input_values.size()    > " << input_values.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;


    /* prepare output tensor */
    std::vector<TF_Output> outputs;
    TF_Output out_op = { TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, LAYERNAME_OUTPUT), 0 };
    if (out_op.oper == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Can't init out_op" << std::endl;
        return 3;
    }
    outputs.push_back(out_op);

    std::vector<TF_Tensor*> output_values(outputs.size(), nullptr);
    TF_Tensor* output_tensor = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, output_dims.data(), output_dims.size(), 6 * sizeof(float));
    output_values.push_back(output_tensor);

    /* prepare session */
    TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
    TF_SessionOptions* options = TF_NewSessionOptions();
    TF_Session* sess = TF_NewSession(graph, options, status);
    TF_DeleteSessionOptions(options);

    if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK) {
        TF_DeleteStatus(status);
        return 4;
    }

    /* run session */
    TF_SessionRun(sess,
        nullptr, // Run options.
        &inputs[0], &input_values[0], inputs.size(), // Input tensors, input tensor values, number of inputs.
        &outputs[0], &output_values[0], outputs.size(), // Output tensors, output tensor values, number of outputs.
        nullptr, 0, // Target operations, number of targets.
        nullptr, // Run metadata.
        status // Output status.
    );

    if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK) {
        std::cout << "Error run session (status=" << TF_GetCode(status) ;
        TF_DeleteStatus(status);
        return 5;
    }

    TF_CloseSession(sess, status);
    if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK) {
        std::cout << "Error close session";
        TF_DeleteStatus(status);
        return 6;
    }

    TF_DeleteSession(sess, status);
    if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK) {
        std::cout << "Error delete session";
        TF_DeleteStatus(status);
        return 7;
    }

    // Assign the values from the output tensor to a variable and iterate over them
    float* out_vals = static_cast<float*>(TF_TensorData(output_values[0]));
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Output values info: " << *out_vals++ << "\n";
    }

    TF_DeleteTensor(input_tensor);
    TF_DeleteTensor(output_tensor);
    TF_DeleteGraph(graph);
    TF_DeleteStatus(status);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 実行時のエラーは、Status= 3 TF_INVALID_ARGUMENT　になります。

Answer (score 1):

なんとなくできましたので、自己解決にて回答しておきます。

## pbファイルがうまくできていなかった件

---

まず、h5　ファイルから　pb　ファイルの作成が、tensorflownoバージョンで
一見できてるように見えて使用できないようでした。
見た目ではわからないので要注意でした。

変換過程で下記バージョンにすると使用可能なpbファイルができました。

## tensorflow 1.15

## keras 2.2.4

別バージョンでトレーニングしたh5ファイルを、上記バージョンにて読み込み→保存
model.save('changevarsion.h5')

同じ、tensorflow 1.15　環境下にて、pbファイルへ変更。
-------------------------　google colab 使うと簡単にバージョン変えれるのが便利ですね。

下記でできること確認しました。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>
#include "tf_utils.hpp"

//#define MODEL_FILENAME  "ep_156_ls_0.1.pb"
//#define INPUTIMAGEPATH  "Valid_pic/"
//#define INPUTIMAGENAME  "Valid_pic/ten__146.bmp"
//#define IMAGE_BATCH     1
//#define IMAGE_SIZE      224
//#define IMAGE_CH        3
//#define LAYERNAME_INPUT  "input_1"
//#define LAYERNAME_OUTPUT "dense_2/Softmax"
//#define ELEM_OUT     6
//#define NUM_DISP_OUTPUT     3
//#define ZERO_ONE     1


// MNIST CNN
//#define MODEL_FILENAME  "201229_conv_mnist.pb"
//#define INPUTIMAGEPATH  "/"
//#define INPUTIMAGENAME  "6.jpg"
//#define IMAGE_BATCH     1
//#define IMAGE_SIZE      28
//#define IMAGE_CH        1
//#define LAYERNAME_INPUT  "input_1"
//#define LAYERNAME_OUTPUT "dense/Softmax"
//#define ELEM_OUT     10
//#define NUM_DISP_OUTPUT     3
//#define ZERO_ONE     1


// VGG16
#define MODEL_FILENAME  "201229_conv_VGG16_.pb"
#define INPUTIMAGEPATH  "/"
#define INPUTIMAGENAME  "lion-768x512.jpg"
#define IMAGE_BATCH     1
#define IMAGE_SIZE      224
#define IMAGE_CH        3
#define LAYERNAME_INPUT  "input_2"
#define LAYERNAME_OUTPUT "predictions/Softmax"
#define ELEM_OUT     1000
#define NUM_DISP_OUTPUT     5
#define ZERO_ONE     0



static int displayGraphInfo()
{
    TF_Graph* graph = tf_utils::LoadGraph(MODEL_FILENAME);
    if (graph == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Can't load graph" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    size_t pos = 0;
    TF_Operation* oper;
    printf("--- graph info ---\n");
    while ((oper = TF_GraphNextOperation(graph, &pos)) != nullptr) {
        printf("%s\n", TF_OperationName(oper));
    }
    printf("--- graph info ---\n");

    TF_DeleteGraph(graph);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());

    /* read input image data */
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(INPUTIMAGENAME);
    cv::imshow("InputImage", image);

    /* convert to 224 x 224 RGB image (normalized: 0 ~ 1.0) */
    cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    if (MODEL_FILENAME == "201229_conv_mnist.pb") { cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY); }
    cv::resize(image, image, cv::Size(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE));
    if (MODEL_FILENAME == "201229_conv_mnist.pb") { image = ~image; }
    cv::imshow("InputImage for CNN", image);
    if (ZERO_ONE == 1) { image.convertTo(image, CV_32FC1, 1.0 / 255); }
    if (ZERO_ONE == 0) { image.convertTo(image, CV_32FC1, 1.0); }

    std::cout << "image > " << image.rows << " x " << image.cols << " x " << image.channels() << std::endl;
//    std::cout << cv::format(image, cv::Formatter::FMT_NUMPY) << std::endl;
//   std::cout <<  image.data << std::endl;



    /* get graph info */
    displayGraphInfo();

    TF_Graph* graph = tf_utils::LoadGraph(MODEL_FILENAME);
    if (graph == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Can't load graph" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    /* prepare input tensor */
    std::vector<TF_Output> inputs;
    TF_Output input_op = { TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, LAYERNAME_INPUT), 0 };
    if (input_op.oper == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Can't init input_op" << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }
    inputs.push_back(input_op);

    const std::vector<std::int64_t> input_dims = { IMAGE_BATCH, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_CH };      // こことデータ次元あっていないと例外がスローされる
    const std::vector<std::int64_t> output_dims = {  1, ELEM_OUT };

    std::vector<float> input_vals;
    if (ZERO_ONE == 0) { std::vector<int> input_vals; }

    input_vals.reserve(IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_CH);
//    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_CH; ++i) {
//        input_vals.insert(input_vals.end() , 0.5);
//    }

//    image.reshape(0, 1).copyTo(input_vals); // Mat to vector

    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_SIZE; ++i) {
        input_vals.insert(input_vals.end(), image.ptr<float>(i),  image.ptr<float>(i) + IMAGE_CH  * IMAGE_SIZE );
    }


//    image = image.reshape(0, 1);
//   image.copyTo(input_vals);
//    for (int b = 0; b < IMAGE_BATCH; b++)
//   {
//        input_vals[b].reserve(IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_CH);
//        std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
//        for (int r = 0; r < image.rows; r++)
//        {
//            input_vals[b].insert(input_vals[b].end(), image.ptr<float>(r), image.ptr<float>(r) + IMAGE_CH);
//        }
//    }

    std::cout << "OK)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "input_vals (size)" << input_vals.size() << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << " > " << input_vals.at(i) << " , ";

    }
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Min. " << *std::min_element(input_vals.begin(), input_vals.end());
    std::cout << "  Max. " << *std::max_element(input_vals.begin(), input_vals.end()) << std::endl;


    std::vector<TF_Tensor*> input_values;
    TF_Tensor* input_tensor = tf_utils::CreateTensor(TF_FLOAT,
        input_dims.data(), input_dims.size(),
        input_vals.data(), image.rows *image.cols*image.channels()  * sizeof(float));

    input_values.push_back(input_tensor);

    std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "type of tensor element > " << TF_TensorType(input_tensor) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "number of Dimensions   > " << TF_NumDims(input_tensor) << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < TF_NumDims(input_tensor); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "   dimension "<< i << "> " << TF_Dim(input_tensor,i) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "size of type           > " << TF_TensorByteSize(input_tensor) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pointer                > " << TF_TensorData(input_tensor) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "No of element          > " << TF_TensorElementCount(input_tensor) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "input_values.size()    > " << input_values.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << input_tensor << std::endl;

    // Optionally, you can check that your input_op and input tensors are correct 
    // by using some of the functions provided by the C API. 
    std::cout << "Input op info(OperationNumInputs): " << TF_OperationNumInputs(TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, LAYERNAME_INPUT)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Input op info(OperationNumOutputs): " << TF_OperationNumOutputs(TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, LAYERNAME_INPUT)) << "\n";


    /* prepare output tensor */
    std::vector<TF_Output> outputs;
    TF_Output out_op = { TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, LAYERNAME_OUTPUT), 0 };
    if (out_op.oper == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Can't init out_op" << std::endl;
        return 3;
    }
    outputs.push_back(out_op);

    std::cout << "TFoutput: " << TF_OperationOutputNumConsumers(out_op) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Output op info: " << TF_OperationNumOutputs(TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, LAYERNAME_OUTPUT)) << "\n";

    std::vector<TF_Tensor*> output_values(outputs.size(), nullptr);
    TF_Tensor* output_tensor = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, output_dims.data(), output_dims.size(), ELEM_OUT * sizeof(float));
    output_values.push_back(output_tensor);

    // As with inputs, check the values for the output operation and output tensor 
    std::cout << "Output: " << TF_OperationName(TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, LAYERNAME_OUTPUT)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Output: " << TF_OperationOpType(TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, LAYERNAME_OUTPUT)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Output: " << TF_OperationDevice(TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, LAYERNAME_OUTPUT)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Output: " << TF_OperationNumOutputs(TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, LAYERNAME_OUTPUT)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Output info(NUM_DIMS): " << TF_NumDims(output_tensor) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Output info(0): " << TF_Dim(output_tensor, 0) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Output info(1): " << TF_Dim(output_tensor, 1) << "\n";

    std::cout << "inputs size            > " << inputs.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "outputs size           > " << outputs.size() << std::endl;


    /* prepare session */
    TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
    TF_SessionOptions* options = TF_NewSessionOptions();
    TF_Session* sess = TF_NewSession(graph, options, status);
    TF_DeleteSessionOptions(options);

    if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK) {
        TF_DeleteStatus(status);
        return 4;
    }



    /* run session */
    TF_SessionRun(sess,
        nullptr, // Run options.
        &inputs[0], &input_values[0], inputs.size(), // Input tensors, input tensor values, number of inputs.
        &outputs[0], &output_values[0], outputs.size(), // Output tensors, output tensor values, number of outputs.
        nullptr, 0, // Target operations, number of targets.
        nullptr, // Run metadata.
        status // Output status.
    );

    if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK) {
        std::cout << "Error run session (status=" << TF_GetCode(status) ;
        TF_DeleteStatus(status);
        return 5;
    }

    TF_CloseSession(sess, status);
    if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK) {
        std::cout << "Error close session";
        TF_DeleteStatus(status);
        return 6;
    }

    TF_DeleteSession(sess, status);
    if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK) {
        std::cout << "Error delete session";
        TF_DeleteStatus(status);
        return 7;
    }

    // Assign the values from the output tensor to a variable and iterate over them
    std::vector<int> prediction_index(NUM_DISP_OUTPUT+1 , 0) ;
    std::vector<float> prediction_value(NUM_DISP_OUTPUT+1 , 0) ;

    float* out_vals = static_cast<float*>(TF_TensorData(output_values[0]));
    for (int i = 0; i < ELEM_OUT; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_DISP_OUTPUT; ++j)
        {
            if (*out_vals > prediction_value[NUM_DISP_OUTPUT - j]) 
            {
                prediction_value.insert(prediction_value.begin() + (NUM_DISP_OUTPUT - j), *out_vals);
                prediction_index.insert(prediction_index.begin() + (NUM_DISP_OUTPUT - j), i);
            }

        }
        std::cout << i << " Output values info: " << *out_vals++ << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_DISP_OUTPUT; ++j)
    {
        std::cout << j << " : " << prediction_index.at(j) << " : " << prediction_value.at(j) << std::endl;

    }



    TF_DeleteTensor(input_tensor);
    TF_DeleteTensor(output_tensor);
    TF_DeleteGraph(graph);
    TF_DeleteStatus(status);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```